# Cannot list subdirs on first level in dir

Tags: perl, unix

I would like to get list of subdirs (on first level) without "." and ".." in e.g. dir "/var/". I have this perl script but it doesn't work:

```
#!/bin/perl

opendir(my $DH, $ARGV[0]) || die "$!\n";
    my @dirs
    = grep {
      -d "$_" &&
      /[^.]/
    } readdir($DH);
  @dirs = sort(@dirs);

closedir $DH;

print "@dirs\n";
```

Output is:

```
 $ ./_copyplg.pl /var
 <nothing>
```

List of /var

```
$ ls -1a /var
.
..
adm
cache
crash
db
empty
lib
local
lock
log
lost+found
mail
run
spool
tmp
var
www
```

Please where I made mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are saying *"`$_` is a directory and `$_` contains at least one of any character that is not a dot"* in your `grep` block. You need to escape the `.` in the regular expression.

There is no need for the character class `[]` if you just negate the match. It would also make sense to put a *beginning of string* anchor, and make sure you only get `.` and `..`, as you might want to allow directories that contain a dot later on, or even start with a dot, like `/var/.foo/`, which is valid.

```
my $dir = $ARGV[0];
my @dirs = grep { ! /^\.\.?\z/ && -d "$dir/$_" } readdir $DH;
```

It will now match `.` and `..`, but nothing else, and negate those.

Note how you need to add the directory to the `-d` check because `readdir` only returns the file names, not their full path. Because you are not starting the program from `$dir` and you are also not switching your current dir there, this is needed.

> If you're planning to filetest the return values out of a readdir,
>   you'd better prepend the directory in question. Otherwise, because we
>   didn't chdir there, it would have been testing the wrong file.

Check out the [perldoc on `readdir`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readdir.html), as that contains the actual example of how to filter out `.` and `..` as well as the warning about the file names.

---

You should `use strict` and `use warnings 'all'` in your Perl programs. It would not have helped you find the problem in this case, but it will make your life easier.

Comment: You're right I'm missing strict and warning use. I filled it to script.  
But I replaced my "grep" with your "grep" but it **doesn't work**.

Comment: Srry, the result is the same. On the stdout is nothing:     

    $ ./_copyplg.pl /var
    <nothing>

Comment: @waldauf you need to prepend the directory to the `-d` test. This is the exact thing the perldoc on `readdir` explains.

Comment: Escaping `.` isn't necessary inside a character class

Comment: @Borodin fixed. But that doesn't change the fact it would not have worked even with the right path. ;)

Comment: Almost! Your first sentence is correct but the follow-up is wrong. `/[^.]/`, passes anything with a non-dot character in the name, so excludes anything that is all dots, including  `.` and `..`. It also happens to exclude `...` etc. but those are strange node names

Comment: @simbabque: You're right I forgot add $dir in grep. Thx to all for help. :]